# Is a full J2EE server needed for a PHP Client connecting via Thrift to a Java Service?

Tags: java, php, thrift

Java class exposes some method getStuff(); via thrift to a php client so all users interact with are .php files which connect to java via thrift...do i still need tomcat/glassfish etc or does the jdk suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK /JRE would suffice. You do not need a J2EE server.

[Sample Thrift Program](http://fundoonick.blogspot.com/2010/06/sample-thrift-program-for-server-in.html) details about using Thrift with a C++ Client and a JAVA service.

It should help you get started. Once you have written a (Java) Server class to handle the requests - you can run it as a standalone Java application.

Also, look at the [Sample provided on the Thrift Website](http://thrift.apache.org/)

Comment: Does Thrift take care of the fact that multiple people access the Java application at the same time?

Comment: When you write the Server side, you should use Threads. As already shown by the [sample code in the first link above](http://fundoonick.blogspot.com/2010/06/sample-thrift-program-for-server-in.html)

Comment: I see... but this is done via already defined constructs in Thrift...cool...thanks alot!